# How to use the Zend SOAP adapter in a Magento2 payment gateway

Tags: soap, payment-gateway

I would like to make a SOAP request to a payment gateway doing so the Magento2 way. Unfortunately I am struggling with what to me seem incomplete developer docs and a lack of examples to borrow online. I am not wanting to send the customer off to some payment gateway page, I need to have the checkout page take the payment and retrieve a token.

The instructions I have struggled with are here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/gateway-client.html

It says:

> Following is the illustration of how a Zend client can be added in di.xml:

...and then gives no further information on how to use the Zend SOAP classes.

I have had a look at a few other payment gateways and have yet to find one using the SOAP client. Some payment gateways including the Braintree gateway use their own library for communicating with the server.

Does anyone have any knowledge of a payment gateway that uses the suggested method of using the Zend SOAP client to communicate with the payment gateway?